# Android Google Maps v2. getMapAsync() does not run in a separate thread?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is getMapAsync() meant to run on a separate thread? I ask because on my application, when the map loads it appears to do it on the main thread because all UI is unresponsive until it loads. I am doing something wrong? Or am I meant to setup the background task myself?

The code below is my SupportMapFragment sub class. I pass a reference of the callback (onMapReadyCallback) which is implemented in my main activity to this class.

```
public class Map extends SupportMapFragment
{

    private OnMapReadyCallback callback;

    public static SupportMapFragment newInstance(OnMapReadyCallback callback)
    {

        Map map = new Map();
        map.callback = callback;
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)
    {
        super.getMapAsync(callback);
    }
```

And in my main activity, the map fragment is added.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map,Map.newInstance(this),Map.class.getName()).commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is getMapAsync() meant to run on a separate thread?

No, it's not. Synchronous code would get executed at the point you're writing it. When writing asynchronous code you're saying what should happen when a certain event (map loaded) occurs some time in the future. Unless specified otherwise (like in `AsyncTask`) async execution does not imply using a separate thread.

> Or am I meant to setup the background task myself?

Yes, but pay attention where to put the code.

> I pass a reference of the callback (onMapReadyCallback) which is implemented in my main activity to this class.

Wrong. Any code related to the map should be contained within your map fragment (also maintain naming convention, even something stupid like `MyMapFragment` is way better than `Map`).

This means you supply input data via `newInstance`, implement an `onMapReadyCallback` *inside* the `MyMapFragment` (this callback is used primarily to modify the map markers, camera position and so on). And if you really need to let the outside `Activity` know, that the map is ready, you implement [fragment callbacks in this standard way](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will refactor and contain the map code within the map fragment. So regarding the question, which aspect of the code should be run in background? the call to super.getMapAsync(callback) ?

Comment: No, never, that method manipulates the internal map view so it has to run on the main thread. Nothing inside the map fragment should be run in background (as far as I see). Unless there's some heavy lifting that doesn't manipulate the map of course.

Comment: Ah I see. So do I risk a ANR ? On the two phones I tested on (HTC one and Samsung GT-19300), the UI is unresponsive for just maybe 1 to 3 seconds. Im worried about older phones that are much slower. So there is nothing I can do to avoid the un-responsiveness? There is no other heavy lifting that occurs during the map loading just the map loading

Comment: So far I've never seen an ANR even on an old GT-5300, which takes 2-4 seconds to load the map for the first time (subsequent loads are below 1s). Yes, pretty much nothing we can do.